# How process generate message to file `/var/mail/root`?

Tags: linux

When use CentOS, which process generate message in generate? On the other way, how `crond` generate mail to generate?

Comment: ... maybe would be better to ask this question in unix.stackexchange.com WDYT?

Comment: i will try, think you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.